# Customized editor for web app

Tags: javascript

I am working on music web app where user can write a music in script format with English language & then it converts to Indian language in table format & user can play it. Currently it uses html 'textarea' to write script.

So to simplify script writing in textarea I want to develop a text editor like source code editor where it will mark some words in special color, line numbers, highlight selected line, give suggestions . . . .

I want all these capability to html 'textarea'. I searched on google & I found two libraries which can I modify for my use

http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html

http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html
Is there any other solution or suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: [ace.js](http://ace.c9.io/)?

Comment: I would recommend codemirror because it is quite easy to use. I don't know about editarea but it seems less "complete".

Comment: It seems codemirror is easy to use . . . thank you

Answer (score 0):

With my expirence, I recommend [ace.js](http://ace.c9.io/)( an embeddable code editor written in JavaScript). It has so much features and functions to allow you write a customized editor in the browser, you even can use it in desktop app by using nodewebkit.

Bellow is demo:
[image]

http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I downloaded this project from GitHub, but it says "You can build it by running node Makefile.dryice.js" but I dont know how to build it. Also I want to use it instead of textarea, will it convert textarea into editor & can I access it content by document.getElementById('textareaId').value, because many of my logic is based on this

Comment: @user3467180 For example, first you need add ace.min.js in your html file, and add a `div` whose `id` is "editor", then  `var editor = ace.edit("editor");` , using "editor.getSession().getValue();" you can get the content.